# SQL combine two queries grouped with new names

Tags: sql, group-by, count, union

I don't know if the question is phrased correctly since I'm not sure what I'm looking for. Sorry for that...

I have an PHP-script which creates a pie-chart and takes input from SQL-query as follows:

```
Column | COUNT(Column)
x      | y
```

For instance I ask for gender pie-chart and work with:

```
gender | COUNT(gender)
female | 17
male   | 13
```

or nationality pie-chart:

```
nationality | COUNT(nationality)
us          | 3
uk          | 8
es          | 4
```

I get these result easy with a query like

```
SELECT myColumn, COUNT(myColumn) FROM myTable GROUP BY myColumn ORDER BY COUNT(myColumn)
```

Now I wanted a pie-chart with alive/dead people. In my table I have bornDate and deceasedDate. Hence I have to do something else to get my desired:

```
alive | COUNT(alive)
alive | 16
dead  | 4
```

I can get alive people with

```
SELECT alive.*
FROM persons AS alive
WHERE alive.deceased = NULL OR alive.deceased = '0000-00-00' AND alive.born != '0000-00-00'
```

and dead people with:

```
SELECT dead.*
FROM persons AS dead
WHERE NOT dead.deceased = NULL OR dead.deceased != '0000-00-00'
```

So the question is, how do I combine this to get

```
alive | COUNT(alive)
alive | 16
dead  | 4
```

?

I guess it involves COUNT() and GROUP BY, but I don't know how. Perhaps also UNION?

Thank you!

Comment: `deceased = NULL` is a meaningless condition.  It never evaluates to true.

Comment: ok, thank you, will update.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do it by using a case statement and a group by on that case statement...

```
DECLARE @persons TABLE (
                          [id] int not null IDENTITY(1,1),
                          born varchar(10) NULL,
                          deceased varchar(10) NULL
                        )

INSERT INTO @persons
(born,deceased)
values('2019-01-01','2019-07-08')
,('2020-05-03',NULL)
,('2000-03-10','0000-00-00')
,('0000-00-00',NULL)
,('2008-01-01',NULL)

SELECT CASE WHEN ISNULL(Per.deceased,'0000-00-00') = '0000-00-00' THEN 'Alive'
            WHEN ISNULL(Per.deceased, '0000-00-00') <> '0000-00-00' THEN 'Dead'
         END AS [CountType]
        ,COUNT(*) AS Total
FROM @persons AS Per
WHERE ISNULL(Per.born,'0000-00-00') <> '0000-00-00' 
GROUP BY CASE WHEN ISNULL(Per.deceased,'0000-00-00') = '0000-00-00' THEN 'Alive'
              WHEN ISNULL(Per.deceased, '0000-00-00') <> '0000-00-00' THEN 'Dead'
         END
```

**Results from above code**

| CountType | Total |
| --- | --- |
| Alive | 3 |
| Dead | 1 |

Comment: Thank you for your elaborate answer! I get an error however.. `Incorrect parameter count in the call to native function 'ISNULL'`. Your answer is very similar to @eshirvana, and that query works.. I will study the differences. Thank you!

Comment: @Robbas - not sure why you got that error message. Are you using MySQL or SQL?

The MySQL equivalent of the SQL ISNULL is IFNULL

Comment: Thank you, that worked. I am using MariaDB.

Answer (score 1):

you can do it by this query:

```
SELECT 
   case when COALESCE(deceased,'0000-00-00') AND born != '0000-00-00' then 'alive' else 'dead' end as Alive
   , count(*) as Count
FROM persons
group by case when COALESCE(deceased,'0000-00-00') = '0000-00-00' AND born != '0000-00-00' then 'alive' else 'dead' end
```

Comment: Thank you! Works great! Now I will study it to make sure I understand it (: